# Using Autofilter With Formula Criteria

Tags: vba, excel

Actually i have a question about how can i use the AUTOFILTER of EXCEL through VBA but by using a formula.

Let me explain : see this table below for example :

```
ID|EMPLOYE|SALARY
-----------------
1   ALLAN  3000
4   BOB    2500
2   MAX    800
3   TIM    200 
6   TOM    0
```

So what i want is to filter this table by calculating the sum of  percents of each salary and stop at 80 %

the of salaries is " total = 6500 "

3000 -> 46%
2500 ->  38%

46%+38%= 84% > 80%

So after the filter the table will be :

```
ID|EMPLOYE|SALARY
-----------------
1   ALLAN  3000
4   BOB    2500
```

I've tried with the auto filter but it doesn't work

Comment: Well it's hard to know if we can help you when we can't see the code you have tried.  And if you haven't tried any code, then you should probably use a macro recorder to get the syntax you need.

Comment: Oh sorry  i forgot i'll put it now :p

Answer (score 1):

**Without VBA**

In **D2** enter:

```
=SUM($C$2:$C2)/SUM($C$2:$C$7)
```

and copy down

In **E1** enter:

```
80%
```

In **E2** enter:

```
=IF(AND(D2>$E$1,D1>$E$1),1,0)
```

and copy down

Then set the filter on column **E** to show only the **0's**

[image]

Comment: @user3604687  you could even hide column **D** when you are done.